# PHP : Get the value of Dropdown and pass it to another dropdown

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, combobox

I have a problem right now [PHP]. I have a dropdown and its loading my database for the first page, when I proceed to the next page it also have a dropdown where its also loading the my database and also I can get the value of my dropdown in the first page using an echo only.

This is the scenario:
I choose in the dropdown first page the "Letter A" and when I click the button it will proceed to the next page. The dropdown in the second page loaded the items in the database but instead of "-select-" is the first index in the dropdown I want is "Letter A" will be the first index.

This is my code in first page for drowdown:

```
 <select name="id">
            <option value="" >- select -</option>

            <?php
        include 'connect.php';

        $q = mysql_query("select fldNetname from tblnetwork");



        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q))
        {
          echo "<option value='".$row1[fldNetname]."'>".$row1[fldNetname]."</option>";

        }
    ?>
        </select>
```

and this is my code in second page for dropdown:

```
if ($get_ID != "") 
{
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $get_ID;
    //echo "show()";
} 
else
{
    echo "No Network Selected";
    echo "<br/>";

    //echo "hide()";
}
```

?>

```
    <option value="">- select -</option>

    <?php
        include 'connect.php';

        $q = mysql_query("select fldNetname from tblnetwork");



        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q))
        {
          echo "<option value='".$row1[fldNetname]."'>".$row1[fldNetname]."</option>";

        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you go to the next page, are you posting that last form from the previous page??

Comment: Yes. The first and second is just the same.

Comment: No I mean the value from the dropdown, is it being posted as a $_GET to the next page....like you didn't post your <form> action, so Im just wondering how youre passing it

Comment: Sorry.. I have a form and this is the code "<form name='form' method='post' action="form.php">" then in the second page "$get_ID = $_POST['id'];" I used this for displaying it and pass it to variables because I'm using it in my code for if else.

Comment: aah I see....ok...as long as $get_ID, is the correct variable to be checking against :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

changing (on the second page)

```
 <option value="">- select -</option>
```

to

```
<option value="<?php echo $yourVar; ?>"><?php echo $yourVar; ?></option>
```

Then in the while loop, skip the value selected to prevent a duplicate choice.
Something like:

```
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {
        if($yourVar != $row1[fldNetname]){
                echo "<option value='".$row1[fldNetname]."'>".$row1[fldNetname]."</option>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: He'll end up with two copies of the same value in the menu then....it works, but not optimal

Comment: If the values are strings, use strcmp() in the if statement.

Comment: This only works if both the "value" and display text are the same. If your value was "4" and your display text was "Letter A", this would result in your selected index being "4" rather than "Letter A", and "Letter A" would be missing from the list.

Comment: Jacob, I agree. However, from the code above it seems that the value and the display text are the same.

Answer (score 2):

On your second page, you need to check whether the value is the same as the one you received from the first page:

```
echo "<option value='".$row1[fldNetname]."' " . (($row1[fldNetname] == $get_id)?"selected":"") . ">".$row1[fldNetname]."</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

if $get_ID, is actually your $_GET['id'] value, then just do...

```
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {          
      echo "<option value='".$row1['fldNetname']."'";
      if($row1['fldNetname']==$get_ID){echo "selected='selected'";}
      echo ">".$row1['fldNetname']."</option>";

    }
```

Or as one line...

```
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{          
 echo "<option value='".$row1['fldNetname']."' " . (($row1['fldNetname'] == $get_ID)?"selected='selected'":"") . ">".$row1'[fldNetname']."</option>"
}
```

Comment: I'm using POST because I'm passing it to variable then use it in my if else query. But then I created a new variable for that but there's an error saying that "Notice: Use of undefined constant fldNetname - assumed 'fldNetname'"